# Sql - NOT IN combined WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine NOT IN with a WITH in T-SQL. But can't get it to work. Is it possible?

Example:

```
    select name 
    from Persons
    where id NOT IN 
    (
        WITH result (numbers)
        AS
        (
            select number from num
        )
        select numbers from result
    )
```

Comment: The `NOT IN` result when a NULL is returned is a bit surprising to many people. That's why I usually recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Is it an exercise, or you can apply a more simple way?

Comment: Why are you using `WITH` at all???

Comment: Cause in the WITH clause I select data in a multiple join query that we group and reselect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WITH` keyword cannot be used inside a subquery, it needs to be before the main query.

```
WITH result (numbers)
AS
(
    select number from num
)
select name 
from Persons
where id NOT IN 
(
    select numbers from result
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got the answer, but just want to show the alternate way to solve the same if someone is interested in the future.

```
SELECT name 
FROM Persons
WHERE id NOT IN (select number from num)
```